# Dropbox Python API on PC - V1 not available?

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I just started learning how to use the Dropbox Python API.

My systems:

`win 10 PC Python 3.5.1 installed dropbox 5.2.2 with pip`

`Raspberry pi Jessie Python 3.5.1 (compiled) installed dropbox 5.2.2 with pip`

On my PC, I can't seem to get the API V1 to work. There is no dropbox.client. I tested API V2 and it works (upload and download).

On my raspberry pi, I tested both API V1 and V2 and they both work. So I was wondering why API V1 doesn't work on my PC. Dropbox is not doing a good job with API V2 docs and examples and I can find more V1 reference and examples.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205789796-Dropbox-API-for-python-on-windows-missing-API-V1- ]

Comment: Seems like this isn't the best place to ask dropbox questions. I'll stick with the dropbox forum for future questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why. The dropbox api docs need some cleanup. I got mixed up between API V1 tutorial and V2 installation guide. My rapsberry pi must have come with dropbox API V1 installed so it worked.

V1 installation:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/python

V2 only needs the second line.